# Create a new script tag (Shopify) Error: Invalid URI "/"

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Based on [this](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag#create) tutorial, I tried the below code. I'm trying to add a new script to the web page.

```
request.post(accessTokenRequestUrl, {
      json: accessTokenPayload
  })
  .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
          const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
          // DONE: Use access token to make API call to 'shop' endpoint
          const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/shop.json';
          const shopRequestHeaders = {
              'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          };


          const createScriptTagUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/script_tags.json';
          const scriptTagBody = {
              "script_tag": {
                  "event": "onload",
                  "src": "https:\/\/djavaskripped.org\/fancy.js"
              }
          }

          request.get(shopRequestUrl, {
                  headers: shopRequestHeaders
              })
              .then((shopResponse) => {
                  res.status(200).end(shopResponse);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                  res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description);
              });
          request.post(createScriptTagUrl, {
                  json: scriptTagBody
              }, {
                  headers: shopRequestHeaders
              })
              .then((scriptResponse) => {
                  res.status(200).end(scriptResponse);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                  res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description);
              });
```

However, I get `RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/"`

Am I missing anything? Or is the src value is having some problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using get method to create the script tag instead of post. Please use post method and also remove \ from the src.

Thanks

Comment: I tried with `request.post(createScriptTagUrl, { json: scriptTagBody }, {headers: shopRequestHeaders})` However, the issue still persists. With \ or without \

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the below code. Basically, the request body was supposed to be sent as JSON.

```
request.post({
    url: createScriptTagUrl,
    body: scriptTagBody,
    headers: shopRequestHeaders,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(body)
    }
});
```